# Help for finding a reference IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, initial-value-problems

I have found the following theorem online: 
If the functions p and g are continuous on the interval $I: \alpha < t < \beta$
containing the point $t = t_0$, then there exists a unique function $y = \gamma(t)$ that
satisfies the differential equation

$$y'(t)+p(t)y=g(t)$$

for each $t \in I$, and that also satisfies the initial condition $$ y(t_0)=y_0$$
where $y_0$ is an arbitrary prescribed initial value.

But I need to have a valid reference for it. So do anyone know some book, where it is stated and proved, such that I can reference it.

Comment: Any book on differential equations will discuss the solution formula for this problem (and that there is a solution formula strongly hints for uniqueness). Most books will also discuss the important case of linear ODE of which this is a special case. There a simple application of the fundamental theorem gives existence and uniqueness as long as the coefficients are continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, could you maybe give an example of one of such books?